# How to get Emmet to work with "Code with me" feature?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, emmet

I have Emmet in my PhpStorm 2021.1 using *Emmet Everywhere*.

When I joined my colleague (who works on WebStorm) using JetBrains' "Code With Me" feature, I cannot use Emmet anymore.

They have "Emmet Everywhere" installed in WebStorm and can use it without problem. I also additionally added this plugin after connecting.

But no matter what I try, I can't use Emmet nor do I see Emmet in `Settings -> Editor`.

Is there a way to get this working? Should I also use WebStorm? Or is it simply not possible currently while live coding?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-3139 I guess

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work currently, please follow [CWM-1664](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-1664) for updates